# Can stored database value be used as a query key word?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I receive list of user ids and versions. Then I should return users which are updated (their version was increased). Is there any way in which I can use unknown id from database as an index of array users but without for loop. Below I tried something like that but it does not work:

```
var users = req.body
var ids = Object.keys(users)

User.find({
   _id: { $in: ids },
   __v: { $gt: users['$_id']}
 })
   .select('firstName lastName email avatarPath')
   .exec(function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
       logger.error('User 500 ' + err)
       return res.status(500).json({
         code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
         message: config.errorCode.status500.message
       })
     }

     return res.json({
       data: result
     })
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to either get all of the users from the database:

```
User.find({
  _id: { $in: ids },
})...
```

and then instead of:

```
return res.json({
  data: result
})
```

you can do:

```
return res.json({
  data: result.filter(user => user.__v > users[user._id])
});
```

or you may try to build a query object:

```
let query = {$or: ids.map(id => ({_id: id, __v: {$gt: users[id] }})};
```

and use that in the query:

```
User.find(query)...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried in both ways, but the second one solved my problem.